# Help with an RX simple Sample for this

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I searched for a sample for this, but could not find something that explains clearly how to set it up using RX:
I have this requirement...

1. In a WPF app, i have a list box
2. A dispatcher timer routine adds some random numbers to a local List every say 2 seconds
3. Now i want to setup an observable/observer to watch this List<int> as it keeps building up, and add the most recent number added, into the list box's items collection.

Sounds very simple, and i have done the third bit in a background thread  (no RX, but with a standard lookup on list<int>)and added to the listbox easily.
When trying to do the same without a background worker etc and just using RX, i am stuck.

Apologies for a possible stupid question (for you RX experts out there), but please help on how to get this WPF done using RX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When working with Rx you need to keep in mind the duality between `IEnumerable<T>` & `IObservable<T>` (as well as `IEnumerator<T>` & `IObserver<T>`).

You should always look for objects that implement `IEnumerable<T>` and consider how you would replace them with `IObservable<T>`.

In your question you say that you have a timer adding some numbers to a `List<int>` which you want to observe and add the new numbers to a list box. So I would consider replacing the list with an `IObservable<int>`. The trick here isn't about watching a list (or an `ObservableCollection<int>`) but instead it is about using Rx as a core part of your code.

So, here's a simple example.

Start with the core elements described in your question:

```
var dispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
var random = new Random();
var listBox = new ListBox();
```

Create an observable from `dispatchTimer`:

```
IObservable<IEvent<EventArgs>> ticks =
    Observable.FromEvent(
        h => dispatchTimer.Tick += h,
        h => dispatchTimer.Tick -= h);
```

Query the observable to create a new observable of random numbers:

```
IObservable<int> randomNumbers =
    from tick in ticks
    select random.Next(1, 11);
```

Now, subscribe to the random numbers observable to update the list box:

```
_updateListBoxSubscription =
    randomNumbers.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(n => listBox.Items.Add(n));
```

The `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` call will make sure that the numbers are added to the list box on the UI thread.

You need to define a field or a property to hold a reference to the subscription so that it doesn't get garbage collected. This is exactly what event handler fields do when you add a handler, but with Rx you must explicitly do it.

```
private IDisposable _updateListBoxSubscription;
```

There you go - you now have a list box being updated from random numbers generated at the interval specified in the time.

It's that simple. I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks :) I will play around with this. Tnx for your time.

Comment: Upvote for the ObserveOnDispatcher() couldn't find that anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

This all looks great but you have effectively killed your testability of your code. You will struggle to unit test this code quickly as you will need to be running a Dispatcher Frame (yuck!).

Lets flip ths on it head on not use a DispatcherTimer, but use the Rx Scheduling and Interval method.

So the code is

```
var random = new Random();
var ticks = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Dispatcher);
var randomNumbers = from tick in ticks
                    select random.Next(1, 11);
_updateListBoxSubscription = randomNumbers
    .Subscribe(n => listBox.Items.Add(n));
```

However this is difficult to test as you have a direct reference to the DispatcherScheduler which in turn references the Dispatcher.

What you want to do is inject the scheduler (IScheduler) so that is can be mocked when testing.

```
var random = new Random();
var ticks = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _schedulerProvider.Dispatcher);
var randomNumbers = from tick in ticks
                    select random.Next(1, 11);
_updateListBoxSubscription = randomNumbers
    .Subscribe(n => listBox.Items.Add(n));
```

and then in you tests you return a TestScheduler instead of a DispatcherScheduler.

Check my blog posts on [scheduling](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/06/rx-part-6-scheduling-and-threading.html) and this one on [testing](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/10/rx-part-8-testing-rx.html) in the [Rx introduction](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/08/reactive-extensions-for-net.html) series for a full description.
**UPDATE**: Better content for learning scheduling with Rx can be found in my book [IntroToRx.com](http://introtorx.com/), specifically the chapter on [Scheduling and Threading](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing, but it sounds like `List<int>` is the problem here - it doesn't "natively" support Rx, in that it doesn't have any means of notifying observers when a new item is added.

When you subscribe to a `List<int>`, it will immediately just dump the current contents to the subscriber - it won't hang around and listen for extra changes.

Could I suggest that [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is probably more appropriate for you?

Comment: I see, Thanks Jon, so using OC<int> how do i do it then please. I am more interested in seeing the RX code in action. A simple sample will help... will be greatful to you. I am trying to get my heads around this cool RX thing...

Comment: @Reader: I'm afraid I don't have time to come up with an Rx example now, but have a look at the `ObservableCollection<int>.CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Thanks i figured out a solution by trying out several things. I did not have to use an Observable Collection etc. I just used the extension method to get an IObservable (using AsObservable) out of a given IEnumerable (which the list of ints is), and subscribed to it, and all is fine. Thanks.